# Arithmetic progression and proofs

Tags: sequences-and-series

Here is the question I am stuck on

An arithmetic progression of integers an is one in which $a_n = a_0 + nd$, where a_0 and d are integers and n takes successive values 0, 1, 2.... Proof that if one term in the progression is the cube of an integer there will be an infinite number of such terms.

The book this is from only has proof by induction and contridition neither of which seem approate. So I started with an algetrabic proof and got to trying to proof that $(x^3+(n_2-n_1))^{1/3}$ is an integer where x and both n terms are integers. This i could not do. Please could you give me hints of were to go from here, or how to start a (different type) of proof / what proof i should be doing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Suppose that $a_n = b^3$. Now consider $(b+kd)^3, k\in \mathbb N$. Can you find values of $n$ for which these occur in the sequence?

Comment: Where have you got $(b+kd)^3$ from. I can understand that $b^3+kd$ is a term but i can't see why $(b+kd)^3$ has to be even if the statement is true?

Comment: If you expand $(b+kd)^3$, what do you get? Can you write it in the form $b^3 + k'd$?

Comment: Ok so I get $k'=3b^2k+3bk^2+k^3d^3$ (which is an integer) then using this form and rearranging it I get $n=n_n+k'$ where $n_n$ is the n value for the $b^3$ value thus this is the condition and occurs at infinitely many values since k' can take an infinite number of values which is a natural number (but not **all** natural number)??

Comment: That should be $k' = 3b^2k + 3bk^2d + k^3d^2$, but yes, that's the idea.